# Python regex number by looking behind

Tags: python, regex

I am extracting numbers in such format string.

- AB1234
- AC1234
- AD1234

As you see, `A` is always there and the second char excludes `"`. I write below code to extract number.

```
re.search(r'(?<=A[^"])\d*',input)
```

But I encountered an error.

> look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

So is there any convenient way to extract numbers? Now I know how to search twice to get them.Thanks in advance.

**Note A is a pattern , in fact A is a world in a long string.**

Comment: Err, this works. Check your actual code.

Comment: Anyway, why not use a capture group? `r'A\D+(\d+)'`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Can you post your answer for r'A\D+(\d+)' ?

Comment: or: `re.search(r'A[^"](\d*)',input).group(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex in your example works, so I'm guessing your actual pattern has variable width character matches (`*`, `+`, etc). Unfortunately, regex look behinds do not support those. What I can suggest as an alternative, is to use a capture group and extract the matching string -

```
m = re.search(r'A\D+(\d+)', s)
if m:
    r = m.group(1)
```

**Details**

```
A      # your word 
\D+    # anything that is not a digit
(      # capture group
\d+    # 1 or more digits
)
```

---

If you want to take care of double quotes, you can make a slight modification to the regular expression by including a character class -

```
r'A[^\d"]+(\d+)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tye using this regex instead:

```
re.search(r'(?=A[^"]\d*)\d*',input)
```